# FATAL ERROR 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, fatal-error, android-contentresolver

Hi I am getting fatal error when m trying to access storage media...
it pointing to this piece of line:

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://media/external/faces")
```

Comment: Could you provide more details - device, OS version, more code?

Comment: Why are you accessing that uri? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: what i am doing is detecting face in Image and creating rectangle from there i am passing query to fetch detected face .

Comment: My task is to create a rect over a detected face with giving value.Al this value stored in this path "content://media/external/faces" from there i am creating uri of this path and trying to fetch all values in cursor object .But it is crashing giving fatal error